# hibernate query with concat function with using sql server

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to run following query in `sql server`. This is `hibernate query` it is working in my `sql`. I want to run it on `sql server 2005`. What should I do for that ??

```
strQuery = "from TempData where englishLex=:englishLex and category =:category and language=:language and login=:login and domain=:domain group by (concat(englishlex,category)) ";
```

Comment: AFAIK, if it is HQL it should be platform independent.

Comment: But in background I am using sql server database.

Comment: That's irrelevant - HQL is platform independent.

Comment: It should be, but I tried and both `hql` `concat(str1, str2)` and `str1 || str2` is not working in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

concat() is a valid function in HQL.

It looks like the case is incorrect on englishLex which is causing the issue.

try the following...

```
strQuery = "from TempData where englishLex=:englishLex and category =:category and language=:language and login=:login and domain=:domain group by (concat(englishLex,category)) ";
```

Comment: concat function will not work on sql server 2005 .. I want to run it on sql server 2005 ... for that we need to use '+' sign I think.but how to use it ???

Comment: but you are not using sql server 2005, you are using hibernate. Hibernate is supposed to translate the HQL into the appropiate SQL for the designed dialect.

Comment: yes sir but in background I am using sql server database.
I am trasffering my project from my sql to sql server thats why it is giving an error.so what should i do for that??

Comment: The database in the back end should always be totally irrelevant, as long as you've set the dialect in the hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: Both of you might be right. Is true that HQL is a "meta sql", a glue to align all different vendors's non standard additions to ANSI SQL. But as long as I remember, not every function is implemented in all DDBB and you can too embed proprietary function's calls in HQL. This can be why it runs in MySql and fails on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server you don't have the concat function, instead you could simply use a + sign. Have you tried that?

```
strQuery = "from TempData where englishLex=:englishLex and category =:category and language=:language and login=:login and domain=:domain group by (englishlex + category) ";
```

Comment: yes sir i tried this but it is giving an error that Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'temptable.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I'ts very helpfull in this cases to use SQL Server Profiler to see wich queries are generated by the ORM and better guess how it work or how to improve the generated query.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As the [official manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) says, we can use `||` or `concat` to combine two `String`s.

In my case the following is working in SQL Server 2012:

```
Query query = currentSession().createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT u FROM UserBean u WHERE CONCAT (u.name, ' ', u.surname) like :fullname");
```

Mind that `UserBean` is the Java bean class name, and as it's in Java code, must be exactly same as the class name.